# Ruby + Rails3: really weird assignment of array problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my test:

```
@board.disp_s
@board.state = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
@board.disp_s
```

corresponding output:

```
Layout:
nilnilnil 
nilnilnil 
nilnilnil 

Layout:
100 
100 
110
```

now...  I'm pretty sure I told it to be

```
100
100
000
```

code from my model: http://pastebin.com/2Mpu7tU7

I'm sure that none of my methods being called by the test are modifying the `@board_layout`.... so I'm confused.

Comment: It would be better to include all the code here rather than in an external pastebin link.

Comment: I did that, cause the code is.. around 70 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disp_s method is not computing the indexes correctly.

```
  def disp_s
    puts "Layout:"
    WIDTH.times do |row|
      WIDTH.times do |col|
        print @board_layout[col * row + col]
      end
      puts " "
    end
```

The `col * row + col` should likely be `WIDTH * row + col`.

I haven't looked carefully enough at your code to be sure there are no other issues, but this would definitely print incorrect values.

Comment: lol, thanks. Silly mistake. Guess I wast just staring at it too long.